# How to find derivative of $\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces, solution-verification

Here is what I've tried: $\alpha\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-a_{i}\right)^{2},\ \  \beta\left(y\right)=\sqrt{y}, \ \ \ \gamma\left(z\right)=z^{p}$.
Clearly: $\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p}=\gamma\circ\beta\circ\alpha\left(x\right)$.
so I should get that $D_{\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p}}\left(x_{0}\right)$
or $\triangledown\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p}\left(x_{0}\right)$
is, by the chain rule : $$p\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p-1}\frac{1}{2\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert }2\left(x-a\right)=p\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p-2}\left(x-a\right)$$
which is a vector, it's $i$'th coordinate is given by $p\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert ^{p-2}\left(x_{i}-a_{i}\right)$.
Of course, if $p<2$ the derivative isn't defined in $x=a$ and if
$p\geq2$ it's defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Am I missing
something?

Comment: That's correct. You can do it shorter: $\|x-a\|^p=(\|x-a\|^2)^{p/2}$.